# TIC TAC TOE GAME - python

Tags: python, pycharm, tic-tac-toe

i wrote a "tic tac toe" game in python(pycharm). At the end of the game i asked the user if he wants to play again: if he pressed 'y' the game began again, and if he pressed 'n' the game/code stopped. do you know how can i show him an error massege like: "you entered a wrong answer! please try again:" when he doesn't press any of this letters but somthing else? for example:
"Would you like to play again? "fnj"(his answer). And show this massage until he enter a correct answer?

```
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

def playTicTacToe():
    rows,cols = 3,3
    winLength = 3
    board = makeNewBoard(rows, cols)
    moves = 0
    player = 1

    while moves < rows*cols:
        row,col = getMove(board, player)
        board = setPiece(board, row, col, player)
        if (didWin(board, player, winLength)):
            printBoard(board)
            print ""
            #print '%s   The Player %s  color.GREEN + color.Bold + "-->" + color.END, """ IS THE WINNER OF THE GAME!!!""" + color.END % (color.GREEN,getPieceLabel(player),
            print color.RED + color.BOLD + "The Player" + color.END, getPieceLabel(player), color.RED + color.BOLD + "IS THE WINNER OF THE GAME!!! " + color.END
            return
        player = otherPlayer(player)
        moves += 1
    print color.RED + color.BOLD + "TIE GAME!" + color.END


def makeNewBoard(rows, cols):
    return [([0]*cols) for row in xrange(rows)]


def getRows(board):
    return len(board)

def getCols(board):
    return len(board[0])

def getPiece(board, row, col):
    return board[row][col]

def setPiece(board, row, col, value):
    board[row][col] = value
    return board

def isEmpty(board, row, col):
    return (getPiece(board, row, col) == 0)

def isOnBoard(board, row, col):
    rows = getRows(board)
    cols = getCols(board)
    return ((row >= 0) and (row < rows) and
            (col >= 0) and (col < cols))

def getPieceLabel(piece):
    if (piece == 1):
        return "|" + color.PURPLE + color.BOLD + "X" + color.END + "|"
    elif (piece == 2):
        return "|" + color.BLUE + color.BOLD + "O" + color.END + "|"
    else:
        return color.BOLD + "|_|" + color.END

def printBoard(board):
    print "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    rows = getRows(board)
    cols = getCols(board)
    for row in xrange(rows):
        for col in xrange(cols):
            piece = getPiece(board, row, col)
            label = getPieceLabel(piece)
            print label,
        print


def didWin(board, player, winLength):
    rows = getRows(board)
    cols = getCols(board)
    for startRow in xrange(rows):
        for startCol in xrange(cols):
            if (didWin1(board, player, winLength, startRow, startCol)):
                return True
    return False

def didWin1(board, player, winLength, startRow, startCol):
    for drow in xrange(-1,+2):
        for dcol in xrange(-1,+2):
            if ((drow != 0) or (dcol != 0)):
                if (didWin2(board, player, winLength,
                            startRow, startCol, drow, dcol)):
                    return True
    return False

def didWin2(board, player, winLength,
            startRow, startCol, drow, dcol):
    rows = getRows(board)
    cols = getCols(board)
    for step in xrange(winLength):
        row = startRow + step*drow
        col = startCol + step*dcol
        if (not isOnBoard(board, row, col)):
            return False
        elif (getPiece(board, row, col) != player):
            return False
    return True


def otherPlayer(player):
    return 1 if (player == 2) else 2


def oops(msg):
    print "  ", msg, color.RED + color.BOLD + "Try again." + color.END


def readInt(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
        except:
            oops(color.RED + color.BOLD + "Input must be an integer." + color.END)

def getMove(board, player):
    while True:
        printBoard(board)
        print "Enter move for player:" + getPieceLabel(player)
        row = readInt("  Row --> ") - 1
        col = readInt("  Col --> ") - 1
        if (not isOnBoard(board, row, col)):
            oops(color.RED + color.BOLD + """\n \n Out of range (not on the board)!""" + color.END)
        elif (not isEmpty(board, row, col)):
            oops(color.RED + color.BOLD +"""\n Already occupied!""" + color.END)
        else:
            return (row, col)


def finish():
    answer = raw_input(color.PURPLE + color.BOLD + """Would you like to play again?! (press \'y\' for yes and \'n\' for no):""" + color.END)
    if answer.lower() == "n":
        print ""
        print color.BLUE + color.BOLD + "Bye Bye! See you next time! :)" + color.END
        return True
    if answer.lower() == "y":
        print (color.BLUE + color.BOLD + """\nGreat choice! The game will start again""" + color.END)
        return False












def main():
    while True:
        playTicTacToe()
        if finish():
            break








if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Wrap both ifs in the finish function in a while loop stating to continue while answer.lower() does not equal "n" and does not equal "y". You could also do an infinite loop since you are returning in both ifs.

Comment: So you 'wrote' a tic-tac-toe but you don't know what a while loop is ?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the finish function as follows:

```
def finish():

    while True:

        answer = raw_input(color.PURPLE + color.BOLD + """Would you like to play again?! (press \'y\' for yes and \'n\' for no):""" + color.END)
        if answer.lower() == "n":
            print ""
            print color.BLUE + color.BOLD + "Bye Bye! See you next time! :)" + color.END
            return True

        elif answer.lower() == "y":
            print (color.BLUE + color.BOLD + """\nGreat choice! The game will start again""" + color.END)
            return False

        else:
            print 'Not valid input...'
```

By this way the program ignores invalid inputs and asks the user again.

PS. I would suggest to insert a mechanism for exiting before the completion of the game in the case the user wants to terminate the game.

Comment: and for your suggestion: how cant i do it? sorry but im a new user :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if answer.lower() == "n":
        print color.BLUE + color.BOLD + "Bye Bye! See you next time! :)" + color.END
        return True
elif answer.lower() == "y":
        print (color.BLUE + color.BOLD + """\nGreat choice! The game will start again""" + color.END)
        return False
else:
    print (color.BLUE + color.BOLD + """\nyou entered a wrong answer! please try again:""" + color.END)
        return False
```